# How to show that the series of functions $\sum \frac{x^{2n}}{(n+x)^2}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Here's the exercise I'm trying to answer:
Determine whether or not the given series of functions converges uniformly on the indicated set. Justify your answers. a.) $\sum \frac{x^{2n}}{(n+x)^2}$ for $x\in[0,1]$

I know that it does converge uniformly on [0,1] (because the textbook tells you so), but I'm at a loss on how to justify it. I'm pretty sure I should show that the sequence of partial sums converges uniformly on [0,1] but I don't understand how I could do that... do I need to find an expression for the sequence of partial sums $(S_n)$? Or is there another way I can show that it converges uniformly?

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Answer (score 1):

Since $x \in [0,1]$, it follows

$$n+x\ge n \iff \dfrac{1}{n}\ge \dfrac{1}{n+x}$$

Now

$$x^{2n}\le 1^{2n}=1 \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
Clearly we have:
$$\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(n+x)^2}\le\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
Finally apply comparison test.